# Monotouch av-capture-frames example using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xamarin.ios, avfoundation

I am using the AVCaptureFrames example for monotouch from the example shown here: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/AVCaptureFrames the problem I have is that each frame that is captured and redisplayed in a UIImageView that is orientated with the home button on the bottom the image seems to be rotated 90 degrees [image: Example of portrait view]; however if I rotate the device so that the home button is on the right, the image is displayed as expected [image: Example of a landscape view]. Also if I turn the app landscape the other way the image is upside down.

Any advice how to rotate the image captured from AVFoundation to orient the same way the device is being held?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you setup the correct preview layer orientation? Follows a sample from my own app, change to your settings.

```
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.FromSession(captureSession);
    previewLayer.Orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    previewLayer.VideoGravity = "AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill";
    previewLayer.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    this.View.Layer.AddSublayer(previewLayer);
```

Does this helps?
BR

Comment: Keep it in sync with the view controller orientation.

Comment: I did not, but i will try this later this week and let you know

Comment: The Orientation property still worked in my iOS7 application. Apple's documentation says it's deprecated, but I could not find a new API... so I got desperate and tried the old one.  thankfully it still worked on both iPhone and iPad.